# Hair exploding randomly (unwanted)

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I have character with hair added. And an animation running 4xx frames. And a hair/particle-system hopping along. And when I bake it it runs fine for most frames but every now and then it freaks out completely!
This happens using Blender 2.77 and 2.79 (same .blnd-file, fresh bakes)
Images here are neighbouring frames. First one OK second one absurd.

I have tried various settings for hair - now I have a version where I only really fiddled with the length. Nothing fancy. Straight out of the box hair.
The hair is added to a mesh that doesn't change at all - except location-rotation.

A possible explanation - PERHAPS - is that I have added the hair AFTER adding motion/animation. Not sure this can be a problem but I am looking for any kind of explanation.

[image]
[image]

PS. If this is a know problem with a known solution I have googled very poorly on the matter. A lot of searching and reading precedes this question.

Comment: try turn of collison modifier.